# Parent / Child Click Event Handling (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I've been looking around for the answer in vanilla JS and can't seem to find anything without reference to jquery's stopPropagation.

I have a "div1" of which I've applied an eventlistener to which opens a URL in a new window. I've also got a "div2" with "div1" of which I'd like to be able to interact with via an eventListener as well.

However, as you could probably imagine, right now, clicking on the div2 just activates the eventListener for div1. Is there a way to prioritize clicks or accommodate for the fact that div2 sits in div1?

[Image Representation of Div Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpQhc.gif)

Comment: stopPropagation is vanilla javascript. Also maybe show some of the HTML and JS you have in order for people to help and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `stopPropagation` is one way to make sure events don't fall through to the next element in the hierarchy:

```
div1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('Div1 Clicked Directly!');
});

div2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Div2 Clicked!');
});
```

Comment: That's it! I'm not sure why I was overthinking this. Thanks very much.